# NginX URL rewrite regex (get rid of special characters ://)

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, ngx-http-rewrite-module

I'm trying to figure out how to use the NginX rewrite so I can load the page

```
https://example.com/page.php?url=https://www.domain2.com/1-2-3-4-5
```

using this URL

```
https://example.com/page/www.domain2.com/1-2-3-4-5
```

So what I'm trying to do is basically get rid of the .php?url=https:/

Can anyone help please?

I've tried to follow the [documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html) but I suppose I'm too dumb for it.

My rewrite rule looks like this:

```
location /page.php {
rewrite ^/page/(.*)$ /page.php?url=https://$1? last;
}
```

Using this rule, the page loads the index instead.